# OSSをdockerで構築したものにソースコードの変更を行いたい

Tags: docker

OSSのデベロッパーが提供しているdocker imageを元に環境構築をし、ロゴを消したり、機能を追加したい場合
どうすれば変更を加えたソースコードをコンテナに反映させることが出来ますか？

OSSのソースコード
https://github.com/Leantime/leantime
docker image
https://hub.docker.com/r/leantime/leantime
https://github.com/Leantime/docker-leantime

Comment: どういうことについて知りたいのかをはっきりさせるため、知りたい問題をより具体的にしたり、追加の詳細を書き加えたりしてください。現状のままだと何についての質問なのかが分かりづらいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leantime 本体を Docker イメージに組み込んでいるのは [`Dockerfile` のこの部分](https://github.com/Leantime/docker-leantime/blob/8607f72/Dockerfile#L24-L26)

```
RUN curl -LJO https://github.com/Leantime/leantime/releases/download/v${LEAN_VERSION}/Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
    tar -zxvf Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz --strip-components 1 && \
    rm Leantime-v${LEAN_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

のようなので、ここで取得しているファイルを "*変更を加えたソースコード*" に挿げ替えた上で[イメージをビルド](https://docs.docker.jp/engine/reference/commandline/build.html)すれば実現できるかと思います。